# Displaying error in blade with error key

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am returning the custom error using `return back()->withErrors()` approach, exactly like this:

```
return back()->withErrors([
    'A' => 'XXX',
    'B' => 'YYY
])
```

Now, if I can use `{{ dd($errors) }}` in my blade, it shows that the errors are returned like so:

```
ViewErrorBag {#208 ▼
  #bags: array:1 [▼
    "default" => MessageBag {#209 ▼
      #messages: array:2 [▼
        "A" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "XXX"
        ]
        "B" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "YYY"
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I try using `{{ dd($errors->all()) }}`, it returns an array, however I don't want to access it through the array.

What I want is to be able to use its key and return the error by the key `{{ dd($errors->B) }}`

What is the proper way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write like this in the controller

```
redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors();
```

in templates check and type for example so

```
@if ($errors->has('name'))
   <span class="help-block">
       <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
   </span>
@endif
```

Comment: `->withInput()->withErrors()` wasn't even necessary. `$errors->first('B')` works like charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This method automatically redirects you to press and shows errors

```
$data = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Access through array `$errors['A']` or convert the array to object by

```
$errors = (object)$errors;
```

And then access like `$errors->A` or `$errors->B`